# Interpreting rawPrediction from Spark ML LinearSVC

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, apache-spark-ml

I am using Spark ML's LinearSVC in a binary classification model. The `transform` method creates two columns, `prediction` and `rawPrediction`. Spark's docs don't provide any way of interpreting the `rawPrediction` column for this particular classifier. This question has been asked and answered for other classifiers, but not specifically for LinearSVC.

The relevant column from my `predictions` dataframe:

```
+------------------------------------------+ 
|rawPrediction                             | 
+------------------------------------------+ 
|[0.8553257800650063,-0.8553257800650063]  | 
|[0.4230977574196645,-0.4230977574196645]  | 
|[0.49814263303537865,-0.49814263303537865]| 
|[0.9506355050332026,-0.9506355050332026]  | 
|[0.5826887000450813,-0.5826887000450813]  | 
|[1.057222808292026,-1.057222808292026]    | 
|[0.5744214192446275,-0.5744214192446275]  | 
|[0.8738081933835614,-0.8738081933835614]  | 
|[1.418173816502859,-1.418173816502859]    | 
|[1.0854125533426737,-1.0854125533426737]  | 
+------------------------------------------+
```

Clearly this isn't simply the probability of belonging to each class. What is it?

Edit: Since the input code has been requested, here's a model built on a subset of features in the original dataset. Fitting any data with Spark's LinearSVC will produce this column.

```
var df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("/FileStore/tables/full_frame_20180716.csv")


var assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("oy_length", "ah_length", "ey_length", "vay_length", "oh_length", 
                      "longest_word_length", "total_words", "repeated_exact_words",
                      "repeated_bigrams", "repeated_lemmatized_words", 
                      "repeated_lemma_bigrams"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

df = assembler.transform(df)

var Array(train, test) = df.randomSplit(Array(.8,.2), 42)

var supvec = new LinearSVC()
  .setLabelCol("written_before_2004")
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.001)

var supvecModel = supvec.fit(train)

var predictions = supvecModel.transform(test)

predictions.select("rawPrediction").show(20, false)
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------------+ 
|rawPrediction | 
+----------------------------------------+ 
|[1.1502868455791242,-1.1502868455791242]| 
|[0.853488887006264,-0.853488887006264] | 
|[0.8064994501574174,-0.8064994501574174]| 
|[0.7919862003563363,-0.7919862003563363]| 
|[0.847418035176922,-0.847418035176922] | 
|[0.9157433788236442,-0.9157433788236442]| 
|[1.6290888181913814,-1.6290888181913814]| 
|[0.9402461917731906,-0.9402461917731906]| 
|[0.9744052798627367,-0.9744052798627367]| 
|[0.787542624053347,-0.787542624053347] | 
|[0.8750602657901001,-0.8750602657901001]| 
|[0.7949414037722276,-0.7949414037722276]| 
|[0.9163545832998052,-0.9163545832998052]| 
|[0.9875454213431247,-0.9875454213431247]| 
|[0.9193015302646135,-0.9193015302646135]| 
|[0.9828623328048487,-0.9828623328048487]| 
|[0.9175976004208621,-0.9175976004208621]| 
|[0.9608750388820302,-0.9608750388820302]| 
|[1.029326217566756,-1.029326217566756] | 
|[1.0190290910146256,-1.0190290910146256]| +----------------------------------------+ 
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: Post the code and some data which is returning such output

Comment: @VivekKumar I understand that it is desirable to have on-topic questions and I would also encourage someone to do so, but this is a pretty complete question with a clear and precise problem definition. Instead of down-voting, flagging and holding, it would be helpful to suggest a better stack, such as data science or crossvalidated.

Comment: @jonwhithers https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sconfluentus When I downvoted and flagged, it was because the question did not had the code which is necessary for reproducing the output. And why do you think that datascience is the best place for this?

Comment: @VivekKumar because the question was not about code, it was about the output of a model, which was present in the first incarnation. Seeing the code does not make the output easier to understand, and so more appropriate to CrossValidated or DataScience stacks, where folks are expecting modeling questions...there is no need to provide the data and code to produce output for a linear regression to interpret the p-values if a coefficient table is present, and there is also no need to see the data to describe to format of a rawPrediction from spark...provided you know how that model works.

Comment: Also, my issue is not with flagging for correction, it is with down voting overall good questions asked by new-comers (notice, no points, no answers, first question) simply because it needs refinement. Ask for the refinement...if it gets ignored for a few days then slam it...I feel like we discourage new people by down voting them before we even try to help them succeed. Teaching starts with setting clear objectives and helping people reach them, down votes are discouraging...this was not awful, just not YET complete...

Answer (score 1):

It is `(-margin, margin)`.

```
override protected def predictRaw(features: Vector): Vector = {
    val m = margin(features)
    Vectors.dense(-m, m)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is mention by arpad, it is the margin.

And the margin is:

```
      margin = coefficients * feature + intercept    
                            or
                     y = w * x + b
```

If you divide the margin by the norm of the coefficients, you will get the distance to the hyperplane for each data point.